# Why the Size getting from 'docker image inspect' is not the same with 'docker image ls'

Tags: docker, docker-cli

first I using 'docker image inspect' command to get the size of my image , the Size is 2773668963 Byte. Then I get the size using 'docker image ls', it shows 2.77G. But the 2773668963 Byte convert to GB is 2.58G.

Comment: Just looks like the normal confusion between [gigabytes (GB)](https://www.google.com/search?q=2773668963+byte+in+gb) and [gibibytes (GiB)](https://www.google.com/search?q=2773668963+byte+in+gib).

Comment: ok, Thanks. I have found the code in https://github.com/docker/go-units/blob/master/size.go.